# How to delay UI feedback when AppBarButton is touched in WP 8.1

Tags: events, windows-phone-8.1

I need to add delay (2000ms) to AppBarButton touch event before any kind of user feedback is shown by the UI. The highlight colour should appear after the delay, not before it. How this can be done in WP 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the styles. I don't think you can delay the touchdown of a standard button, therefore you may have to use a RepeatButton.

```
<RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource RepeatButtonStyle1}" Delay="2000" Interval="100000" />
```

Then you can customize the style, and more specifically the Pressed VisualState storyboard:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="2000" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

If you need it to be an AppBarButton, you may just change its style to delay the keyframe, however you would have to handle the 2s timer using the DispatcherTimer and be sure the button is still on pressed state, but you also have to reset the timer if the Release event is raised.